# exportar componente de otro modulo - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy intentando exportar un componente de un modulo para que sea accesible y utilizado en el modulo principal. He estado siguiendo esta guía-> https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/trabajar-modulos-angular.html - que lo explica bastante bien, pero me salta el siguiente error:

> Error: src/app/shared/prueba1/prueba1.component.ts:8:14 - error
> NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be
> resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
>
> 8 export class Prueba1Component implements OnInit {

```
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

mi intención es exportar el componente "prueba1", que se encuentra en el modulo "SharedModule", al modulo principal "AppModule".

He buscado preguntas similares aquí en stackoverflow y en otros foros, pero ninguna de las respuestas "más votadas" me ha servido, ejemplo-> https://qastack.mx/programming/60290309/error-ng6002-appears-in-the-ngmodule-imports-of-appmodule-but-could-not-be-res

**shared.module.ts->**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Prueba1Component } from './prueba1/prueba1.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Prueba1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    Prueba1Component
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**app.module.ts->**

```
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment.prod';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
/*Firebase*/
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule, BUCKET } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/navbar/navbar.component';
/*ngx-translate*/
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslationComponent } from './shared/translation/translation.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/footer/footer.component';
import { FollowboxComponent } from './shared/followbox/followbox.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './pages/home-page/home-page.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Prueba1Component } from './shared/prueba1/prueba1.component';
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC3mQG7C45bxD6W3Zl_mUlj8cQcHOZXISU",
  authDomain: "lowstsky-web.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "lowstsky-web",
  storageBucket: "lowstsky-web.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "211432009730",
  appId: "1:211432009730:web:bb1d7f9ebaf9bc2e54771b",
  measurementId: "G-S0KPX27PP2"
};
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FollowboxComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    TranslationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    PagesModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig), //firebase
    AngularFirestoreModule, // firestore
    AngularFireAuthModule, // auth
    AngularFireStorageModule, // storage
    HttpClientModule, //ngx-translate
    TranslateModule, //ngx-translate
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => {
          return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
        },
        deps: [ HttpClient ]
      }
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    Prueba1Component
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: BUCKET, useValue: 'lowstsky-web.appspot.com' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**prueba1.component.ts->**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prueba1',
  templateUrl: './prueba1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prueba1.component.scss']
})
export class Prueba1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```